# cannot borrow as mutable because it is already borrowed, when implementing graph

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to implement a graph structure by having each node store references to its neighbors. Specifically, I am trying to make a grid where each node has references to up to 4 neighbors - like a "2D linked list".

But I get an error when assigning the references. This minimalistic example reproduces my issue:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Node<'a> {
    neighbor: Option<&'a Node<'a>>, // optional reference to another Node
}

fn main() {

    // a bunch of nodes:
    let mut nodes: Vec<Node> = vec![ Node{neighbor: None}; 100];

    // I want node 0 to have a reference to node 1
    nodes[0].neighbor = Some(&nodes[1]);

}
```

The following error is produced:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `nodes` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     nodes[0].neighbor = Some(&nodes[1]);
   |     ^^^^^------------------------------
   |     |                         |
   |     |                         immutable borrow occurs here
   |     mutable borrow occurs here
   |     immutable borrow later used here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

I am struggling to figure out how this is supposed to be done in Rust. Should I be using pointers instead?

Comment: why don't you store the indexes instead of references to the nodes themselves?

Comment: I was hoping I'd be able to make the remainder of my program independent of this structure that was used for instantiating the nodes. But maybe that's a bad idea in Rust?

Comment: you can definitely do like that, is just indexes are simple too. You may want to take a look at `Rc`.

Comment: It's possible [GhostCell](https://crates.io/crates/ghost-cell) could help you, it's made for exactly this purpose. [Here's a github repo with some collections using it](https://github.com/matthieu-m/ghost-collections) and [here's a reddit post about a 1d linked list](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/minqu0/writing_an_ergonomic_and_efficient_linkedlist_in/)

Comment: ... and if none of the safe approaches work for you (ergonomics, performance whatever) you can always fallback on unsafe blocks and raw pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot implement such data structure exactly for the reason the borrow checker was created. It tells you that your data structure cannot be safe.

The reason it is not safe is quite simple.

Let's say you created a graph with two elements, and the first one references the second one. Now you want the second one to reference the first one. To modify your graph, you will need to gain mutable access to the structure. But if you get the mutable access to it, nothing can stop you from removing the second node from the graph, making the reference in the first node invalid.

Thus, borrow checker won't allow you to do that.

The way to go for you is to use indexes instead of references. This will have additional advantage: when you want to serialize/deserialize your structure, you will have no problems at all doing it.

Comment: It's possiblr to do it with heap allocated nodes via `Rc/Weak`

Comment: Thank you, I now understand why this is not allowed, and unlike I originally thought, it is not a flaw in the compiler

Comment: ... however, in the hypothetical scenario where nodes can get removed, I have to wonder what benefit the index implementation has. It's "safe" from the perspective from the compiler, sure, but indexes become invalid just like references do.

Comment: If you trick compiler (for example using unsafe) and make it let you use references, and accidently dereference invalid reference, you will have memory access violation. It is much worse problem, and much more difficult to debug, then panic in case of using incorrect index without checking.